# Coderbyte Second Great Low - code works but is rejected

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working through the Coderbyte series to get better at Ruby programming.  Maybe this is just a bug in their site (I don't know), but my code works for me everywhere else besides on Coderbyte.

The purpose of the method is to return the 2nd smallest and the 2nd largest elements in any inputted array.

Code:

```
def SecondGreatLow(arr)
  arr=arr.sort!
  output=[]
  j=1
  i=(arr.length-1)
  secSmall=''
  secLarge=''
  while output.length < 1
    unless arr.length <= 2
      #Get second largest here
      while (j<arr.length)
        unless arr[j]==arr[j-1]
          unless secSmall != ''
            secSmall=arr[j]
            output.push(secSmall)
          end
        end
       j+=1
      end
      #get second smallest here
      while i>0
        unless arr[i-1] == arr[i]
          unless secLarge != ''
            secLarge=arr[i-1]
            output.push(secLarge)
          end
        end
        i-=1
      end


     end
  end



  # code goes here
  return output 

end   


# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
SecondGreatLow(STDIN.gets)
```

**Output**

1. Input: [1,2,3,100] => Output: [2,3] (correct)
2. Input: [1,42,42,180] => Output: [42,42] (correct)
3. Input: [4,90] => Output: [90,4] (correct)

The problem is that I'm awarded 0 points and it tells me that my output was incorrect for every test. Yet, when I actually put any inputs in, it gives me the output that I expect. Can someone please assist with what the problem might be? Thanks!

**Update**
Thanks to @pjs answer below, I realized this could be done in just a few lines:

```
def SecondGreatLow(arr)
  arr=arr.sort!.uniq
  return "#{arr[1]} #{arr[-2]}"     
end

# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
SecondGreatLow(STDIN.gets)
```

Comment: Your method expects an array but [`STDIN.gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) returns a string.

Comment: @Stefan You're absolutely right, but the Coderbyte site presents input examples for testing which are arrays. I went ahead and wrote a solution where the first line was `arr = arr.split(/[, ]+/).map{|n| n.to_i} if arr.is_a? String`, and that seemed to pass their tests regardless of whether the input was string or array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to pay close attention to the problem's specification.  Coderbyte says the output should be the values separated by a space, i.e., a string, not an array. Note that they even put quotes around their "Correct Sample Outputs".

Spec aside, you're doing **way** too much work to achieve this. Once the array is sorted, all you need is the second element, a space, and the second-to-last element.  Hint: Ruby allows both positive and negative indices for arrays. Combine that with `.to_s` and string concatenation, and this should only take a couple of lines.

If you are worried about non-unique numbers for the max and min, you can trim the array down using `.uniq` after sorting.

Comment: This is why I love this site. Thank you @pjs.  Thanks to your comment, I was able to figure out how to condense my code from 32 lines to 5. Thank you!  I've updated my question with the output code to help anyone else on this

Comment: @tomtom You're welcome. One minor tweak you could add to your solution: `arr.sort!.uniq!` is sufficient, the `!` versions of the methods act on the array in-place so there's no need for an assignment `arr=...`.  Good job with the string interpolation for your `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check condition for when array contains only two elements. Here is the complete code:

```
def SecondGreatLow(arr)
    arr.uniq!
    arr.sort!
    if arr.length == 2
        sec_lowest = arr[1]
        sec_greatest = arr[0]
    else
        sec_lowest = arr[1]
        sec_greatest = arr[-2]
    end
    return "#{sec_lowest} #{sec_greatest}"
end
```